# Взять длительность трека из VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Пишу скрипт на php! Я новичок и мне необходимо взять длительность музыкального трека из VK. Недаво ВК закрыли эту возможность и передаётся лишь заглушка 20 сек длиной...а мне нужно проверять по скрипту длительность. Так вот вопрос! Можно ли взять другими методами эту длительность? Через другой язык? Или даже через php? Помогите!!! Очень нужно! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Совсем никак, API аудиозаписей полностью закрыт.

Comment: да но ведь если например скачать трек? можно ли так решить этот вопрос?

Comment: или через nodejs как-то? мнеговорили через псевдобраузер как-то можно

Comment: Артём, суть ограничений не в том, чтобы их как-то замысловато обходить, а в том, чтобы в принципе этого не делать.